# Azure Function HTTP Multi-Part POST Not Recognizing Field

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to post to a web service using a multi-part form. However the service is saying it can't recognize the file upload I am trying to send. This is the section for the file upload.

```
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="GOO1242.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOE....... <rest of file>
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

The error is

{
"type": "validation_error",
"detail": "There is no field: "file"."
}

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I've used RestSharp to do this in a C# azure function

```
var apiRequest = await GetRestRequest(request);
var response = await SendRequest(apiRequest, log);

private async Task<RestRequest> GetRestRequest(string requestInput) 
    {

        var uploadRequestInput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadModelRequest>(requestInput);
        var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(uploadRequestInput.Content);
        var uploadBicxRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadModelRequest>(requestBody);

        var apiRequest = new RestRequest("system/archive/document", Method.POST);
        apiRequest.AddParameter("key", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadRequest), "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        apiRequest.AddFileBytes("VersionData", base64EncodedBytes, uploadRequest.PathOnClient, "application/octet-stream");
        apiRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        return apiRequest;

    }
```